# Document Set in Classic Experience: Trying to use an SPWeb object that has been closed or disposed and is no longer valid

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set, classic-experience

When I click on a SharePoint Classic experience document set in a document library, the following error shows (German):

"Trying to use an SPWeb object that has been closed or disposed and is no longer valid."
[image]

This happened overnight for all document sets in this document library. We cannot access the docsethomepage.aspx for a specific document set. We can however see and edit the docsethomepage.aspx on its own when there are no added URL parameters.
We had a look at the Wep Parts on this page but couldn't find anything erroneous.

Could it be that Microsoft has started to deprecate document sets in the classic experience?

Comment: Do you use SharePoint Online in Microsoft 365, or SharePoint Server 2019, SE ?

Comment: SharePoint Online in Microsoft 365

Comment: Did you do any customization on the docsethomepage.aspx?